# How do I disable IPV4 and use only IPV6 in Ubuntu AWS instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, networking, amazon-ec2

I Spun a Ubuntu machine in AWS with IPV4 and IPV6 addresses. I would like to disable the IPV4 interface which then only IPV6 should be used to pull packaged from `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse` with Egress only Internet Gateway added to the Route table.

Comment: You can not disable the IPv4 part of the interface. The only thing you can do is block all IPv4 traffic in the NACL and remove any external routes to IPv4 ranges. Not all AWS services are IPv6 yet so I’d exercise caution with this approach. Is there any particular reason for this?

Comment: Yes, I am testing a tool with IPV6 and that requires IPV4 to be disabled. When I deleted the IPV4 address the default route is also getting deleted which I am not able to connect to the Internet. I am looking to disable the IPV4 interface and at the same time, I need to connect to the internet as well. If there is any way can you please help me with that.